# Summing multiple values from a data frame using a loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, while-loop

I have a single data frame `data` and a vector `cryptos <- c("btc","eth","bnb","xrp")` (where "btc" and etc. are the names of crypto currencies). I need to create a FOR loop that would sum the values of each coin.
So far, I've managed to 'return' every value with a `print` function:

```
cryptos <- c("btc","eth","bnb","xrp")
for(i in 1:4) {
print(data[data$crypto_name == cryptos[i], 3]) #where 3 is the number of a column with crypto values
}
```

So it prints the given currencies' values:

```
[1] 45065
[1] 2190.07
[1] 459.61
[1] 1.12
```

Yet, I do not want to print these values, just sum them with the use of a loop. Please tell me, how could I possibly do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
sum( data[data$crypto_name %in% cryptos, 3] )
```

A basic sum loop is trival:

```
s = 0
for(i in 1:4) {
s = s + data[data$crypto_name == cryptos[i], 3] 
}
s
```

Comment: This code works just as intended. Many thanks!